# How to ignore system messages on application level? (WM_SettingChange / WM_WinIniChange)

Tags: windows, c++builder

We have an application that misbehaves when the user changes the date format in his Windows region settings. (Yes, the solution would be to fix the misbehaviour--- not the point here.)

Changing the settings braodcasts a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message to all applications. We're trying to avoid our problem by ignoring this message and keep the date format as it was (for now, as a hotfix).

Whatever I do, the `TMonthCalendar` component still changes its format, as well as `TDateTimePicker` which uses `TMonthCalendar` as its popup.

I tried (all with the same result):

- Overriding `TForm::WndProc()`

  ```
  void __fastcall TfrmMainWindow::WndProc( TMessage & msg )
  {
    if( msg.Msg == WM_SETTINGCHANGE )  return;  // ignore

    TForm::WndProc( msg );
  }
  ```
- Setting a hook with `Application->HookMainWindow( hookWindowsMessage );`
- Setting `TApplication.UpdateFormatSettings = false;`
- Setting `Application->OnEvent = onApplicationEvent;` to catch all events... but unfortunately this specific case falls under the "OnMessage only receives messages that are posted to the message queue, not those sent directly with the Windows API SendMessage function." rule.

It would seem that overriding `WndProc()` is almost a good idea, only that it only affects that one window, not the application as a whole. I thought that's what `Application->HookMainWindow()` was for, but apparently not.

Anyone any idea how to solve or circumvent this problem?

Comment: The `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message is not asking for permission to change the settings; it is merely a courtesy notification. Ignoring the message doesn't prevent the change from occurring. It is identical to *not processing* the message. Any control that uses Windows API functions is going to start getting behavior corresponding to the new setting. There's no way around that.

Comment: @CodyGray Very true, unfortunately. I can stop my application from handling the changes (see below). However, I didn't realize that TMonthCalendar is actually using a Win32 API calendar that ignores my application settings. No way around that.

Comment: FYI, `HookMainWindow()` only intercepts messages that were sent/dispatched to the `TApplication` window specifically.  That is not a catch-all for intercepting messages for the entire application as a whole. If you need that, use `SetWindowsHookEx()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Cody Gray states in the comment above, the problem is not the message handling but the `TMonthCalendar` component which uses the Win32 API calendar and thus works *outside* the application context.

However, for all other components (ie. `TDateTimePicker`'s line edit) and internal global variables (like `ShortDateFormat` etc.) it *is* possible to ignore the format change as follows:

```
class TfrmMainWindow : public TForm
{
public:
  __fastcall TfrmMainWindow( TComponent * Owner )
    : TForm( Owner )
    {
      Application->HookMainWindow( hookWindowsMessage );
    }

  __fastcall ~TfrmMainWindow()
    {
      Application->UnhookMainWindow( hookWindowsMessage );
    }

private:
  bool __fastcall hookWindowsMessage( TMessage & msg )
    {
      if( msg.Msg == WM_SETTINGCHANGE )
      {
        String sLParam( (char *)msg.LParam );

        // Check for Region Settings change (not Desktop background etc.)
        if( sLParam.LowerCase() == "intl" )
        {
          return true;  // ignore message
        }
      }

      return false;  // handle message as usual
    }
};
```

Sources:
["Trapping Messages Sent to an Application"](http://www.delphicorner.f9.co.uk/articles/apps7.htm)

["TMonthCalendar displays dates according to the system locale (ignoring the BiDiMode setting)."](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ComCtrls_TMonthCalendar.html)

["The Win32 API provides a control used to select dates on a colorful calendar. The dates used and the way they display are based on the Regional Settings of the Control Panel."](http://www.functionx.com/bcb/controls/monthcalendar.htm)

Comment: Oh, and for my special case, `Application.UpdateFormatSettings = false;` actually works like a charm. :-)